# Can't mock a third party api call

Tags: python, django, mocking

I have a view that perform a third party API call:

```py
from .atoca_api_calls import atoca_api_call

def atoca_api_call_view(request):
  # some code
  data = atoca_api_call(**params)  # the actual API call happens in this func
  # some code
```

My intention is to mock just the `atoca_api_call()` func and not the whole view.

```py
class AtocaTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
      # some code

    @patch('crm.atoca_api_calls.atoca_api_call')
    def test_atoca_call(self, mock_atoca_api_call):
      mock_atoca_api_call.return_value = MagicMock(
        status_code=200,
        response=some_json # just returns some json
      )
      url = reverse('crm:atoca-api-call')  # url related to `atoca_api_call_view`
      response = self.client.post(url, some_others_params)
      # various asserts
```

The test works fine but `atoca_api_call()` is not mocked.
I'm aware of [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch):

```
@patch('crm.views.atoca_api_call', autospec=True)
```

Raises a `ValueError`:

```
ValueError: Failed to insert expression "<MagicMock name='mock.__getitem__().__getitem__().__getitem__()().resolve_expression()' id='140048216397424'>" on crm.Company.atoca_id. F() expressions can only be used to update, not to insert.
```

It's probably a simple issue I don't catch for inexperience, any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i see the `atoca_api_call()` it is mocked. The issue is the return value.

```
mock_atoca_api_call.return_value = MagicMock(
    status_code=200,
    response=some_json # just returns some json
)
```

This should ve a proper response i assume a `JsonResponse` or `Response(data)` not sure what are you returning. Try with:

```
mock_atoca_api_call.return_value = JsonResponse(
    some_json # just returns some json
)
```